# How to build a function f(g(h(...))) using \def\func(#1,#2...)?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\def\g(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9){(#6)*exp((#2)/(#7))+((#6)**2)*exp(2*(#2)/(#7))*(#9)*exp((#4)/(#7)}%

\def\f(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9){1+2*(#6)*exp((#2)/(#7))+((#6)**2)*exp(2*(#2)/(#7))*exp((#4)/(#7))}%

\def\b(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9){exp(-(#3)/(#7))+(#6)*exp(-(#2)/(#7))*exp((#5)/(#7))*exp(-(#3)/(#7))*(1-(#8)*((\f(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9) )/(\g(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9) ))))}%

\def\c(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9){exp(-(#3)/(#7))*(\f(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9) )}%

\def\v(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9){exp((#1)/(#7))*(-(\b(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9) )+\sqrt{ (\b(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9) )**2+\c(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9) })*10**3}%   

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
           xlabel= $\Updelta \upepsilon_I (K_BT) $,
            ylabel=${IC_{50}(mM)}$ / ${[H_2O]}$,
            legend pos=north west,
             grid=major , ymax=20, ymin=0, xmax=-4, xmin=-8] 


 \addlegendimage{empty legend}\addlegendentry[font=\footnotesize ]{$\Updelta \upepsilon_S=-5K_BT $}

%%%%%%%%% MENOS SUBSTRATO %%%%%%%%%%%%
    \addplot[blue,mark=none,
         domain=-8:-3,samples=300, line width=1]
    gnuplot{\v(x,5.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0) };\addlegendentry[font=\footnotesize ]{${[S]}$/${[H_2O]}$$=10^{-6}$}

%%%%%%%%% MAIS SUBSTRATO %%%%%%%%%%%%
   \addplot[red,mark=none,
         domain=-8:-3,samples=300, line width=1]
    gnuplot{\v(x,5,0,0,0,2,1,1,1) };\addlegendentry[font=\footnotesize ]{${[S]}$/${[H_2O]}$$=10^{-2}$}

 %\addlegendentry{Velocidade Normalizada}  
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with Ti*k*Z's `declare function`?

Comment: please complete your example to show the problem. I wouldn't use delimited arguments in that way but given those definitions you can use `\f( {\g(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)` with `{}` to guard the inner calls

Comment: I've tried the way at the code above and an error poped up "! Use of \pgfplots@addplotimpl doesn't match its definition. \pgfutil@ifnextchar ...1\def \pgfutil@reserved@a { #2}\def \pgfutil@reserved@... l.55 ...t{\v(x,5.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0) }; \addlegendentry[font=\foot..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach works fine *if* you replace `\sqrt{...}` by `sqrt(...)` in the definition of `\v`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\def\g(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9){(#6)*exp((#2)/(#7))+((#6)**2)*exp(2*(#2)/(#7))*(#9)*exp((#4)/(#7)}%

\def\f(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9){1+2*(#6)*exp((#2)/(#7))+((#6)**2)*exp(2*(#2)/(#7))*exp((#4)/(#7))}%

\def\b(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9){exp(-(#3)/(#7))+(#6)*exp(-(#2)/(#7))*exp((#5)/(#7))*exp(-(#3)/(#7))*(1-(#8)*((\f(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9) )/(\g(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9) ))))}%

\def\c(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9){exp(-(#3)/(#7))*(\f(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9) )}%

\def\v(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9){exp((#1)/(#7))*(-(\b(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9)
)+sqrt( (\b(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9) )**2+\c(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9) ))*10**3}%   
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
           xlabel= $\Updelta \upepsilon_I (K_BT) $,
            ylabel=${IC_{50}(mM)}$ / ${[H_2O]}$,
            legend pos=north west,
             grid=major ,% ymax=2000, ymin=0, 
             xmax=-4, xmin=-8] 


 \addlegendimage{empty legend}
 \addlegendentry[font=\footnotesize ]{$\Updelta \upepsilon_S=-5K_BT $}


%%%%%%%%% MENOS SUBSTRATO %%%%%%%%%%%%
\addplot [
        blue,id=DoG,
        samples=100,domain=-8:-4,
    ] gnuplot {1.3*exp(-x**2/10) - exp(-x**2/20)};

     \addplot[blue,mark=none,
         domain=-8:-4,samples=300, line width=1]
   gnuplot {\v(x,5.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0)};
    \addlegendentry[font=\footnotesize ]{${[S]}/{[H_2O]}=10^{-6}$}

% %%%%%%%%% MAIS SUBSTRATO %%%%%%%%%%%%
   \addplot[red,mark=none,
         domain=-8:-4,samples=300, line width=1] 
   gnuplot {\v(x,5,0,0,0,2,1,1,1) };
    \addlegendentry[font=\footnotesize ]{${[S]}/{[H_2O]}=10^{-2}$}

 %\addlegendentry{Velocidade Normalizada}  
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For completeness, you can write `f(g(...))` using Ti*k*Z's `declare function`. That is, in principle Ti*k*Z has commands for this situation. Without `gnuplot`, I need to restrict the domain of your plots somewhat because your function seems to explode.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

%
\tikzset{declare
function={g(\Xa,\Xb,\Xc,\Xd,\Xe,\Xf,\Xg,\Xh,\Xj)=(\Xf)*exp((\Xb)/(\Xg))+((\Xf)^2)*exp(2*(\Xb)/(\Xg))*(\Xj)*exp((\Xd)/(\Xg);}}%

\tikzset{declare
function={f(\Xa,\Xb,\Xc,\Xd,\Xe,\Xf,\Xg,\Xh,\Xj)=1+2*(\Xf)*exp((\Xb)/(\Xg))+((\Xf)^2)*exp(2*(\Xb)/(\Xg))*exp((\Xd)/(\Xg));}}%

\tikzset{declare
function={b(\Xa,\Xb,\Xc,\Xd,\Xe,\Xf,\Xg,\Xh,\Xj)=exp(-(\Xc)/(\Xg))+(\Xf)*exp(-(\Xb)/(\Xg))*exp((\Xe)/(\Xg))*exp(-(\Xc)/(\Xg))*(1-(\Xh)*((f(\Xa,\Xb,\Xc,\Xd,\Xe,\Xf,\Xg,\Xh,\Xj)
)/(g(\Xa,\Xb,\Xc,\Xd,\Xe,\Xf,\Xg,\Xh,\Xj) ))));}}%

\tikzset{declare
function={c(\Xa,\Xb,\Xc,\Xd,\Xe,\Xf,\Xg,\Xh,\Xj)=exp(-(\Xc)/(\Xg))*(f(\Xa,\Xb,\Xc,\Xd,\Xe,\Xf,\Xg,\Xh,\Xj)
);}}%

\tikzset{declare
function={v(\Xa,\Xb,\Xc,\Xd,\Xe,\Xf,\Xg,\Xh,\Xj)=exp((\Xa)/(\Xg))*(-(b(\Xa,\Xb,\Xc,\Xd,\Xe,\Xf,\Xg,\Xh,\Xj)
)+sqrt(
(b(\Xa,\Xb,\Xc,\Xd,\Xe,\Xf,\Xg,\Xh,\Xj))^2+
c(\Xa,\Xb,\Xc,\Xd,\Xe,\Xf,\Xg,\Xh,\Xj)))*10^3;}}%   

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
           xlabel= $\Updelta \upepsilon_I (K_BT) $,
            ylabel=${IC_{50}(mM)}$ / ${[H_2O]}$,
            legend pos=north west,
             grid=major , %ymax=20, ymin=0, 
             xmax=-4, xmin=-8] 


 \addlegendimage{empty legend}
 \addlegendentry[font=\footnotesize ]{$\Updelta \upepsilon_S=-5K_BT $}

%%%%%%%%% MENOS SUBSTRATO %%%%%%%%%%%%
    \addplot[blue,mark=none,
         domain=-8:-5,samples=300, line width=1] 
    ({\x},{v(\x,5.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0)});
    \addlegendentry[font=\footnotesize ]{${[S]}/{[H_2O]}=10^{-6}$}

% %%%%%%%%% MAIS SUBSTRATO %%%%%%%%%%%%
   \addplot[red,mark=none,
         domain=-8:-5,samples=300, line width=1] 
    {v(x,5,0,0,0,2,1,1,1) };
    \addlegendentry[font=\footnotesize ]{${[S]}/{[H_2O]}=10^{-2}$}

 %\addlegendentry{Velocidade Normalizada}  
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Worked here to, butt it took too long to complile. Should it be the \Tikzset?

Comment: @ThalesSouzaFreire It takes so long because you set `samples=300`. While you are testing, you should use at most `samples=40` or better less. Once you are happy with the result, you can increase the samples in the final run. And yes, `\tikzset` is probably simpler and safer.

Comment: the gnuplot work  on \tikzset?

Comment: @ThalesSouzaFreire  I could make your above code also work, in principle, after I replaced the `\sqrt{..}` by `sqrt(...)`. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: GREAT! And with \def i can use gnuplot,  which works faster using 300 samples than using 40 samples on \tikzset and no gnuplot (i don't know why).  But worth the time learning another method. Thanks for the help, man! You saved me some hair strands on my read! lol